# Accessing multiple rows from a table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on MVC3 and currently creating a Forum application in asp.net.

Forum allows the users to ask Question and also allows to add comment to the already asked questions...

Currently i need to display the question and comments on click of "details" View but don't know how...:(

I have two tables: Question n Answer where Answer contains a foreign key of Question 
how can I access multiple rows of Answer table for a single Question

Thank you!!

Comment: We need to know what you use for data access. Entity Framework? edmx? DbContext?

Comment: @MarcoAngelucci: I'm using edmx for data access

Comment: The you should have some ObjectContext around, just a linq query against the ObjectContext's entities and you can pick up whatever you want. If you can't find out, provide some more details about your entities and i'll provide examples on how to query them.

Comment: @MarcoAngelucci: Here is my code:
in index link i have written:
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using(var _db=new Model1Container())
            return View(_db.Questions.ToList());
        }
and the view contain 2 links: 1 for details and 1 for delete
in Details i have written:
 public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            using (var _db = new Model1Container())
            {
               Question q = _db.Questions.Find(id);
                return View(q);
            }
        }
which will show Question and its ID

Comment: which will show Question and its ID
now below this i need to show the all Answer
please help in that!

Comment: Haven't you a navigation property on Questions that links to the Answers? If not, you have to simply select from Answers the ones with the foreign id corresponding to the question. Once you have the entities, build a viewmodel to show them all on the same view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing raw SQL here you go.

```
select 
   a.*
from
   question q
   left outer join answer a on a.QuestionID = q.ID
where
   q.ID = 999
```

For EF, simply pull up the question object from context and then iterate over the Answers collection of the Auestion object.